# Material to use for home printed target faces?

Tags: gear, archery, diy

I often print some custom targets on common copy paper. However, as you might already guessed, the paper gets tattered very fast.

Is there any printable (common inkjet) material which is more durable (some foil etc.)?

Printer stats:

- A4
- Color
- Inkjet
- HP Officejet 8600 Pro

Comment: You could print on paper and glue it to card?

Comment: @Aravona Would consume too much time. It's faster to just print out a few more faces :)

Comment: Well you can print on card straight away if your printer can accept that, but to be honest with you, anything else you put through your printer could either jam or damage it - you'd need to list what printer you have and what it says it tolerates printing. Anything else would void a warranty. Do you have an inkjet or a laserjet? Also what size does your printer print to? A3 or A4?

Comment: @Aravona I'll add a few stats. However, I'm looking for something which doesn't tear that easy. So that a bullet/arrow hole is only the size of the shaft - nothing more. Kind of such a foil/paper hybrid. I hope someone can recommend such a material based on experience.

Comment: I wouldn't put foil through a printer, especially the one you have listed. A home office printer is not designed to do what you're asking.  Especially an inkjet, you still need to be able to put something through which is incredibly flexible, so the best you'll get is a thin card - if you try and put something too thick in then you'll just jam the machine.

Comment: Look for a paper that's a higher gsm than office paper which is 80gsm - that printer can accept a maximum of [280g/sm.](http://www.trustedreviews.com/hp-officejet-pro-8600-plus-specs)

Comment: As Aravona said, higher density paper. Also look for something with a woven filament like cotton bond.  quick search: http://www.amazon.com/Classic-Linen-Text-70lb-White/dp/B000YINPTQ/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1450791447&sr=8-5&keywords=pound+woven+printer+paper  (70pound=264gsm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this personally but I would imagine that waterproof/resistant paper used for printing out maps would work well due the slightly plastic feel.

A quick search using your favorite search engine with the terms 'waterproof inkjet paper' ought to give you lots of options.

Comment: +1 This is a good idea, I was facing the same problem some years back. Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Print your faces and stick on cardboard. They last a lot longer. Waterproof paper might help if you're planning to shoot in not so fair weather.